# How to order a query result over a ressource after nested ressources creation date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Posts` and `Comments` in my Rails app. I want to display `Posts` ordered by most recent activities, meaning Posts with a recent comment come first.

I have this SQL and several Problems at the moment:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).order('comments.id DESC').uniq
```

As you can see it joins the two tables and orders the results

The Problems is:

- If `Posts` have no `Comments` then those `Posts` appear allways as first in the descending order they are created, but I want Post A without comments to appear behind Post B which has comments, that are newer then Post A

I would really appreciate your help for solving one of these two problem or both, thank you

**Edit**: 1 Problem was just a careless mistake by me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Post
  .left_outer_joins(:comments)
  .group("posts.id, comments.created_at")
  .order('COUNT(comments.id) DESC, comments.created_at DESC').uniq
```

For pagination error you need to add this line in controller

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

example:-

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  require 'will_paginate/array'
end
```

checkout [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/195)

Comment: I changed it allready and this works like I wanted it, thank you.

Comment: @Pavan Thank you for guide me , but so far as i think it needs to show post to first which was updated at recently, am i right?

Comment: No, he wants the *Posts with a recent comment come first* that means `created_at desc`

Comment: yes I used it with created_at its ok. But thank you man and with the pagination: where do I put the ``require`` line?

Comment: @Pavan Alright am gonna update answer anyway thank you.

Comment: @IljaKO Just put that line first line after controller. please have a look at updated answer.

Comment: @IljaKO Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, also let me know for any further guidance. :)

Comment: Yes of course. You helped me a lot thank you. I just forgot to make ``paginate(page: params[:page])`` at the end of the query :) It was my mistake, no need for require 'will_paginate/array'. Thank you again big help

Comment: @IljaKO Great to know that !